Fundamental group - proof of neutral element
I've been struggling with this for quite some time now.
I want to prove via homotopy $e_x p(t) = p(t)$
I have no problem proving the associativity property and constructing the explicit path homotopy, but I just seem to be incapable of understanding the neutral element property especially the time variable shifting.
So given $p: [0,1] \to X$ and $e_x:[0,1] \to X$ with $e_x$ constant at $x_0$
The composition of the paths is $e_x p(t) = x_0$ (for $0\leq t \leq 1/2)$ and $p(2t -1)$ (for $1/2 \leq t \leq 1$)
So far so good. But now for constructing the homotopy between $p$ and $e_x p$ I just can't get my head around the definition:
$h(t,s) = x$ (for $0 \leq t \leq \frac{1-s}{2})$
$h(t,s) = p(\frac{2}{1+s}t + 1 - \frac{2}{1+s}$) for $\frac{1-s}{2} \leq t \leq 1$
I understand why it is correct, but I just don't get how derive the boundaries for t. For associativity I figured out one can visualize the time on 2 lines and find a continous deformation of the time variable, but how does this work here?
Hope this question is not absolutely dumb

Let's go about how one would derive such a homotopy $h$. Writing $h_s(t) = h(t, s)$, we want to come up with an expression such that
$$
   h_s = \text{ path that is constant at } x_0 \text{ on } [0, (1 - s) / 2] \text{ and runs through } p \text{ in the interval } [(1 - s) / 2, 1] 
$$
Where does the bound $(1 - s) / 2 = 1 / 2 - s / 2$ come from? On one hand, for $s = 0$ we want that $h_0 = c_{x_0} * p$ (I'll use the standard notation $c_{x_0}$ for the constant path at $x_0$ and $*$ for path concatenation¹) while on the other we're aiming for $h_1 = p$, and $s \mapsto (1 - s) / 2$ is the "simplest" continuous function on $[0, 1]$ that is $1 / 2$ at 0 and 0 at 1 (although any other such function would also work here).
The only thing we still need to express is then the "running through $p$ in the interval $[(1 - s) / 2, 1]$" part, seeing as $p$ is a map from $[0, 1]$. This means we're looking for a family of homeomorphisms $\phi_s\colon [(1 - s) / 2, 1] \to [0, 1]$ depending continuously on $s$ such that $\phi_0(t) = 2t - 1$ and $\phi_1 = \mathrm{id}_{[0, 1]}$. The simplest thing you could do is again to take something linear: Since the length of your domain interval is $|1 - (1 - s) / 2| = (1 + s) / 2$ and that of your codomain is 1, the map we are looking for will be of the form $\phi_s(t) = 2 / (1 + s) t + c$ for some constant $c$, and the condition
$$
    0 = \phi_s\big(\frac{1 - s}{2}\big) = \frac{2}{1 + s} \frac{1 - s}{2} = \frac{1 + s}{1 - s} = 1 - \frac{2}{1 + s}
$$
then tells us that $c = 1 - 2 / (1 + s)$, so we have recovered the exact homotopy you were asking about.

¹Please don't ever use $\circ$ for path concatenation, you'll trip yourself and everybody else up.

Thank you so much, this was exactly what I couldn't get the intuition for.
